# Render Markup while waiting for data from load-function in svelte

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, svelte

I know there are some discussions about that. For example here:

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/8640

However, I still do not understand it completely. I have a `+page.svelte` and a corresponding `+page.js` file. In the `+page.js` file I fetch some external data. This might take a second. While doing so I want to at least let the user know that the data is beinf fetched or something. Or even render the markup the does not depend on the data itself.

The code in the `+page.js` looks something like this:

```js
import { fetchAllData } '$lib/utils';

export async function load({ fetch, url }) {
    let id = url.searchParams.get('id');
    let data = fetchAllData(id, fetch);
    return { data };
}
```

I wonder if/how I could do something like this in the `+page.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let data;
</script>

{#await data}
    waiting
{:then d}
    respo
{/await}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although [H.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449679/3617380)'s answer is technically correct, I don't think `+page.js` is the right tool for your use case.

The whole point of having a `+page.js` instead of fetching inside an `onMount` callback is to avoid the "loading" problem.

Let me explain, `+page.js` is executed:

1. on server side for initial route, e.g. enter url in address bar, or hit browser refresh button.
2. on client side for subsequential in-site navigation, e.g. click a link on page A to navigate to page B, then `+page.js` for B is executed on client (both page A and B need to be routes within the same SvelteKit project)

For 1st case, the data loading is processed on server, page won't even render before the data is loaded. So user will have to wait a bit while staring at a blank screen. If this takes long they might feel your website is slow.

For 2nd case, the data loading is actually handled in page A, instead of page B. It'll be like, user click a link on page A, but navigation to page B won't happen **until** `+page.js` finishes executing. So if it takes long, users stay on page A, and might think they missed clicking the link some how, and probably would click it again.

Knowing this behavior should help you decide if `+page.js` is the right tool to your problem.

My suggestion is,

- For normal use case that takes reasonable amount of time to load data, use `+page.js` and you shouldn't have to worry about loading state.
- For special use case where it takes insanely long to load data, then you shouldn't even use `+page.js`. You should just use the good old `onMount(() => fetch(...))` and show a loading inidicator to keep your user patient.

`+page.js` is designed specifically for "normal use case", don't wrestle with the tool, just choose the right one.

Comment: The promise streaming functionality exists exactly for data that takes longer to load or is larger, so why *not* use that?  To me the only valid reason not to use it, would be that the deployment platform does not support it. Using this mechanism also ties into things like data invalidation and keeps the conventions of where data is commonly loaded. It is unclear to me why you take issue with it.

Comment: @H.B. From my past experience `{#await promise}` is rarely practical. If I ever need to consider using `{#await}`, usually it means the case is complex enough that I'd also need more flexible controls than the 3 states it can offer. So I'd rather universally reduce such use cases to the `onMount` approach, to reduce mental burden so to speak.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I would love to just use the tools provided:) I'm just not super experienced and figured it'd be nice to show the user at least that something is happening

Comment: ^Sure, this is just my opinion. Try and see what works for you.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit:* In v2, top level promises are not awaited automatically.

Top level promises in the `data` are automatically awaited before rendering the page, you would have to assign the promise to a deeper property, e.g.

```js
return { deferred: { data: fetchAllData(id, fetch) } }
```

```html
{#await data.deferred.data}
```

[Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises)

(Would recommend renaming things, `data` is not very descriptive and the page data variable is already called `data` as well.)

Comment: thank you very much! Would you say this is "bad practice" ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Ideally everything should just load quickly enough to directly render the page with the data already there but if that is not feasible, using something like this should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

You've pretty much answered your own question, this is a snippet from their official docs(link below) so this works perfectly.

```
<script>
    let promise = getRandomNumber();

    async function getRandomNumber() {
        const res = await fetch(`/tutorial/random-number`);
        const text = await res.text();

        if (res.ok) {
            return text;
        } else {
            throw new Error(text);
        }
    }

    function handleClick() {
        promise = getRandomNumber();
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    generate random number
</button>

{#await promise}
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then number}
    <p>The number is {number}</p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

https://svelte.dev/examples/await-blocks

**Here is a example. I based it off your code :-**

https://svelte.dev/repl/e81ca49d739b4f86a2753aed59443467?version=3.59.1

Comment: This is just a generic explanation of `#await` in Svelte, it is not specific to SvelteKit which has a more defined intended path of getting data from the server onto the page.